# How to maintain identity column value during SQL bulk copy to another table?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am using `SqlBulkCopy` to copy data from one table to another. There are so many tables to do that.

I am copying data with for loop for each tables.

But, I am facing an issue, whenever I copy data from source table to destination table then the identity column values are getting changed.

Suppose there is value like this in identity column of a source table

```
301
305
605
```

but when I copy data than it will imported in destination table like that

```
1
2
3
```

I have tried:

```
    set identity_insert [tablename] ON

    //COPY Data from source to destination
    set identity_insert [tablename] OFF
```

And I have also set `SqlBulkCopyOption.KeepIdentity`
    My c# code

```
          //  Dataservice.KeepIdentity2("SET IDENTITY_INSERT "+tableName+" ON");

            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy =
                 new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionDatabase2"].ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls & SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
            {
                bulkCopy.SqlRowsCopied +=
                    new SqlRowsCopiedEventHandler(OnSqlRowsTransfer);
                bulkCopy.BatchSize = 5000;
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableName;
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(DestinationDatatable);
            }
            //Set Identity insert OFF
          //  Dataservice.KeepIdentity2("SET IDENTITY_INSERT " + tableName + " OFF");
```

Any solution will be highly appreciated

Comment: KeepIdentity is the canonical solution for this. You have a bug in your code. Show it.

Comment: No man, code seems perfect but identity column resets every time in destination table

Comment: Closing question because OP is unwilling to provide information required to diagnose the problem. This makes the question unanswerable. If your code is perfect why is there a problem?

Comment: Ok sorry i didn't mean your word "SHOW IT".. :)

Comment: I have paste my code please take a look.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have the correct idea.  The problem appears to be a boolean logic issue.
You have: SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls & SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity
The values for these two items are:

SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls    = 8 = 00001000

SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity = 1 = 00000001

The boolean "&" operator ands the two values together (meaning keep the bits that are common in binary). The value of this operation results in a zero.
What you really want is an OR: 8 | 1 = 9

new SqlBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionDatabase2"].ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepNulls | SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))

Boolean operators are kind of backward compared with English wording:  If you want to KeepNulls AND you want to KeepIdentity then you need to OR the two values together.